# Test for (curly) brackets in expressions in QGIS 2.14.14 with strpos() weird results

Tags: qgis, expression, string

When trying to find a `strpos()` of a substring containing curly brackets (or brackets anyway as far as I can see) I get `0` as a result.

Test for substring without `{}` works fine:

[image]

Test for substring with `{}` weird result (should be `6`):

[image]

Finding the brackets seems no problem, because `replace()` works as expected:

[image]

Aren't brackets treated as normal characters in `strpos()`, am I missing something? Bug? Feature?

Comment: i see that too (QGIS 2.18.3). escaping them with \ doesn't work either, nor does doubling them up {{}}. if replace was also affected i'd suggest the curly brackets might have some special meaning to the expression parser, but that seems unlikely if replace is unaffected. worth raising a ticket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to double escape the brackets (this applies to any kind of bracket):

```
strpos('This {is} s a test', '\\{is\\}')
```

[image]

Tested on QGIS 2.18.7.

Comment: ha! that might explain why  `strpos( 'test (foo)' ,'[foo]')` equals 6 , if the brackets are 'invisible' :-)

Comment: @StevenKay, yes. If brackets are not double escaped, only the content inside them is read (so, `6` is the correct result in your example). However, the latter seems to work only for `()` and `[]`, not for `{}`.